# Как по нажатию на ссылку <a> выполнить код C# ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Допустим есть cshtml код :

```
<ul>
    <li><a onclick="" href="">Article 1</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="" href="">Article 2</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="" href="">Article 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

И мне нужно при нажатии на эту ссылку показывать разные данные, которые я беру из БД. Данные я вывожу на страницу вот так:

```
@{
    var a = Model.Articles.Single(x => x.Id == 1);
    @Html.Raw(a.Header);
    @Html.Raw(a.Content);
}
```

Но это только для первой статьи, если я модифицирую c# код до  метода:

```
@{
    void GetContent(int id)
    {
        var a = Model.Articles.Single(x => x.Id == id);
        @Html.Raw(a.Header);
        @Html.Raw(a.Content);
    }
}
```

, и буду туда передавать ID вот так: `onclick="GetContent(1)"` , то получится, что кнопка на старте программы раз 10 нажмется и испортит страницу(. Я уже немало вариантов перепробовал и уже совсем нет идей что с этим делать... Пробовал и JS, но у меня что-то не получилось. Может быть мне как-то исправить подход и это плохая идея - уместить статьи на одной странице.

Comment: `И мне нужно при нажатии на эту ссылку показывать разные данные...`, т.е. при нажатии перейти на др.страницу и отобразить данные?

Comment: Нет, я хочу остаться на той же странице, но выполнить код c# который покажет данные из бд. Такое возможно или нужно новую страницу в любом случае?

Comment: В HTML [переопределите](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1768124/12888024) событие нажатия на JS функцию, и отправляйте AJAX запрос на сервер из скрипта.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему отойдя от идеи делать все на одном url.

Как исправил:

Index.cshtml:

```
@model System.String
<ul>
    <li>
        <a asp-controller="Article" asp-action="GetArticle" asp-route-id=1>company_list.php</a>
    </li>
</ul>

@if (Model != null)
{
    @Model
    //Если html страница в контент, то Html.Raw(Model);
}
```

ArticleController.cs:

```
public IActionResult GetArticle(int id) 
        {
            var a = db.Articles.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
            if (a != null)
            {
                
                return View("Index", a.Content);
            }
            return View("Index");
        }
```